# How did this action have that consequence?

Tags: life-is-strange

In the last episode of Life is Strange, Max goes back to

> the beginning of the first episode and alerts David to Jefferson's crimes and hideout.

Returning to the present,

> we see that Jefferson was arrested soon afterwards (the photographs of that replace ones that took part during the intermediate episodes) and so in the present Max is not his prisoner.

Later,

> Max goes even farther back and tears the photo that would be her submission to the contest, intending to make sure she doesn't leave Arcadia Bay. But somehow the result is that Jefferson hasn't been arrested, and it's only after she's already a prisoner that David finds his hideout.
>
> I don't understand how Max not having a photo to submit delayed David finding out about Jefferson. David said Max led him there, which implies she still sent that message in the altered past, but this time around David gets there several days later.

How did altering that bit of the past delay the rest?

Comment: I believe he already had him under surveillance, but since there was no message it happened at its own pace instead of being accelerated.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain how David ended up there anyway, but not why there was no message. And David did say Max led him there.

Comment: There was no message because there was no way back. I can't explain the second part though, but I'm sure it has to be in the episode where the surveillance is revealed.

Comment: And why was there no way back? Max said it's because Jefferson burned the photos, but how did ripping one photo apart cause him to do that when originally he didn't?

Comment: Because he's psychotic. To him that seems like a natural thing to do. Destroy one, destroy them all.

Answer (score 8):

Max originally

> escapes the dark room

by using her diary. After she

> pleads with Jefferson, he

tosses the diary at her and it opens to the page of the photo she took in class.

By tearing up her submission photo

> Jefferson became mad at her (because he thought she was talented and by not submitting a photo he felt she was just wasting it) and

burnt her photos and diary. This meant that the timeline played at like it first did, except she wasn't able to

> escape the dark room anymore because she didn't have that picture to look at. Since she wasn't able to escape, she wasn't able to warn David.

As revealed in Episode 4, David actually had surveillance of the place, so it's conceivable he was just able to figure it out for himself

> seeing as Max and Chloe were both missing (I assume they weren't missing for long, and this may not have contributed to him solving it)

Comment: Also, they uncovered the hay and left a trail in their investigation. David's surveillance would see that and make him investigate. I've said too much, haven't I . . . ?

Comment: This explains everything although I think it's a mistake of the game creators. When coming back from the _gallery reality_ the past was already the one with warning message being sent to David. In this past Jefferson never killed Chloe and never captured Max. So there was no need for her to use the journal photos to come back to the past. In fact she wouldn't even have a chance to do it, because she would never be captured. When  she torn up the photo the only major effect should be her never winning the contest, other than that all should be the same as in the _previous past_.

Answer (score 2):

Before Max

> went back in time and handed Jefferson the photo for her submission,

She

> texted David, warning him about the Dark Room.

So,

> when Max tore up the photo, she didn't change the fact that she texted David, because she did that before handing in the photo.

Max left evidence of her investigation,

> whether you wanted to or not. It is possible that David routinely investigates the barn and/or has it under surveillance, but didn't find anything. However, Max brushing away part of the floor showed David where to go.

This way,

> Max "led him here." The text put the barn under surveillance, and the uncovering alerted him that something was going on.